# PHP-Fpm.d with nginx , how to run sudo at shell exec

Tags: php, linux, shell, nginx

PHP-Fpm.d with nginx , how to run sudo at shell exec

I did the following at /etc/sudoers

nginx ALL= NOPASSWD: /srv/www/user1.somedomain.com/public_html/www_files

I try run this php file inside www_files

1.php

```
echo exec("sudo whoami") . "<br/>";
echo "HI" . exec("whoami");
?>
```

I try access 1.php through my website somedomain.com/1.php and it only output the 2nd line

```
Hi nginx
```

but not the first line even I give sudo permission, whats wrong with my setup .

I need sudo permission to run a bin file at that folder **/srv/www/user1.somedomain.com/public_html/www_files**

**My main objective was to run somebin as root, because if I don't give it root power, I cant shell_exec this somebin through my website.** 1.php was create to test for sudo power

```
/root/somescript-linux-x86_64/bin/somebin
```

In order to run script.php

```
shell_exec("sudo /root/somescript-linux-x86_64/bin/somebin myfile.js");
```

How do I make changes so I can run 1.php as sudo then proceed to run my script.php so it can run the **/root/somescript-linux-x86_64/bin/somebin** using root through website

Answer (score 0):

Update your sudoers file with this, then you will be able run sudo

`Default:nginx !requiretty`